# Unable to create Transactional ORC table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am trying to create a transactional ORC table in Hive using beeline.

```
DDL:

CREATE TABLE employee_trans (
 id int,
 name string,
 age int,
 gender string)
 STORED AS ORC
 TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

I have also set the below properties:

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
```

But I am getting the below error,

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:The table must be bucketed and stored using an ACID compliant format (such as ORC))
```

Can someone please help!

Comment: message:The table must be bucketed ... your table is not bucketed

Comment: Is it necessary that table must be bucketed for transaction tables?

Comment: Yes it is necessary https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this. There are examples in various forums where tables were not bucketed. This helps!